# Error: Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'. while working with provider package flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am working with provider package and receiving below error:

Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.

Tried to infer 'MenuController' for 'T' which doesn't work:
Type parameter 'T' is declared to extend 'ChangeNotifier?' producing 'ChangeNotifier?'.
The type 'MenuController' was inferred from:
Parameter 'create' declared as     'T Function(BuildContext)'
but argument is 'MenuController Function(BuildContext)'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

dart(could_not_infer)
'MenuController' doesn't conform to the bound 'ChangeNotifier?' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'ChangeNotifier?'.darttype_argument_not_matching_bounds
main.dart(30, 11): The raw type was instantiated as 'ChangeNotifierProvider', and is not regular-bounded.

Below is code the code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Storage Dashboard',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
          // dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
              .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
          canvasColor: secondaryColor),
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<MenuController>(create: (context) => MenuController(),),
        ],
        child: HomeScreen(),
      )
      
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kqoN.png)

and here is MenuController class

```
    class MenuController extends ChangeNotifier {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> get scaffoldKey => _scaffoldKey;

  void controlMenu() {
    if (!_scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diXz6.png)

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image&  code seems ok, try to check the menuController import part

Comment: Did you tried with providing the Type of ChangeNotifierProvider like this ChangeNotifierProvider<MenuController>(create: (_).... ???

Comment: I tried   ChangeNotifierProvider<MenuController>(create: (context) => MenuController(),), but this still remains 'MenuController' doesn't conform to the bound 'ChangeNotifier?' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'ChangeNotifier?'.darttype_argument_not_matching_bounds . is it possible because I am using Flutter 3.7.1 and this is happening due to some incompatibility. just a wild thought.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

Gotta write `import './menu_controller.dart';` at the top (or wherever your file is).

Error occurs when you forget to import the file with the  provider in it.